# Get steam item median prices

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

i find url where can have "median_price": but its last info on median. i need info about last 3 days example. 
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=P90%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Factory%20New%29
and i have some question:
-how to get all info about item - float?
-how to get info about all items in one request?

Answer (score -1):

You can use services like steamlytics for the easy work with skins
Through steamcommunity.com/market/ you can not get all the skins for 1 query